# JQueryMobile select text not shown correctly

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I have a select loaded via Ajax and then rendered to JQueryMobile, everything looks right but some times the text of select just gone and back when we scroll! (somthing crazy) the value still selected

What could the reason?

The correct combo box is here
http://s18.postimage.org/oeg0rd0a1/correct_combo.png

After scorrling down and up this is the in correct (Text not showen but the value still selected!!!)
http://s9.postimage.org/pnhwrkue7/incorrect_combo.png

really strange!!

Comment: Are you changing in javascript? If yes you might need to call the `listview("refresh")` method.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Jack after loading the html via Ajax I execute this code `$('select').selectmenu();` when i tried to put `listview("refresh")` i get error in JS and the select not rendered at all ;-(

Comment: This is a known issue with jQuery Mobile. See here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476484/jquery-mobile-1-1-1-custom-select-menu-placeholder-text-not-visible][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476484/jquery-mobile-1-1-1-custom-select-menu-placeholder-text-not-visible

Comment: @AdamD Thanks for your replay but i think they are talking about somthing else, everything is working correctly with me but when i scroll the text hided and back

Comment: can you post your code? or make a jsbin of the problem. Also, what version of jQuery Mobile are you using?

Comment: Sorry I meant 'selectview("refresh")'