# JQuery Mobile Custom Select Menu is visible when unselected

Tags: select, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu, placeholder

I was having the same problem as this question:

[jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 Custom Select Menu - Placeholder Text not Visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476484/jquery-mobile-1-1-1-custom-select-menu-placeholder-text-not-visible)

The above question solved my problem by telling me to use 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js'.  That solved my original problem but caused another.

The select menu is always displayed and doesn't center on the select item like it did before.

After:
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this.  I think I might be able to hide and show the menu if that was the only problem that I was having, but even when selected it is not in the right position.  It should be centered over the select element both horizontally and vertically (if given enough vertical space).

This is caused by the latest release of JQuery, but I also can't download 1.1.1 because it causes the original problem that I had which was solved in the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the menu is displaying relative to the rest of the content - Try adding a css line on there

```
position:absolute;
```

on the menu structure - Another good way to test this would be to load up your site in google chrome and use firebug to see why the menu is positioning lower than the "click point." Just on glance it appears that the menu is appearing relative.

Comment: I just tried that, but it had the same behavior.  The position was already set to absolute by the .ui-selectmenu class.